# Haskell: Is it possible to inject Show and Read?

Tags: haskell

I read this mail [*safe* coerce:four methods compared](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell/2003-August/012372.html), in which methods of type conversions are discussed.

In the first approach, `String` is used as the universal representation and every type which wants to convert to/from other types simply makes itself instances of typeclasses `Show` and `Read`.

However, would this raise a security issue? Is there a way for the input to hijack the process, in a way similar to SQL injection?

Comment: in SQL injection you hijack the server to execute unallowed commands because you did use unchecked user-input so of course you get the same problem if you use user input *unchecked* ... I just don't see where the connection here is

Comment: It depends a lot on what kind of malicious actions the data you parsing is capable of representing. SQL is very mighty, and surely you could create a Haskell DSL equivalent of it. So then just dont `execSQL $ read arbitraryString` and you're safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the attacker can only provide the textual representation for those values and that for SQL injection you mean executing arbitrary code as a result of parsing the input: **no**.

Assuming you have control over instances of `Show` and `Read` and you are careful to keep your code pure, it doesn't matter what input is provided by the attacker, your code is pure and doesn't have side-effects, hence something like "SQL injection" is not possible.

Obviously the attacker could provide an input that requires a lot of time/resources to parse but this is a DoS attack, which is different from an SQL injection-like attack.

Answer (score 1):

On top of my head, when it's unsafe, it's in an obvious way. So basically: don't trust with `read` any input you get from anyone. It's meant for deserialization, so when you do deserialize, make a function to check the sanity of the data you receive.

Otherwise a user could easily change the input (`show` yields very simple text), and bypass smart constructors. Another way to deal with this is create custom, safer, instances. E.g. a lot of containers serialize to something like: `fromList [1,2,3]` instead of `show`ing the underlying structure. Can't have too many problems with that.

Here's a GHCi session for a datatype that is a list with an `Int` for it's size:

```
data LList a = LList [a] Int deriving (Eq, Ord, Show, Read)
let mkLList xs = LList xs (length xs)
-- Module would only expose (LList, mkLList)
read "LList [6,4,2] 6548" :: LList Int
> LList [6,4,2] 6548
```

Now we have a `LList` with the length of 6548 elements... but we only have 3.

Comment: This is only due to the automatically derived instances. You can easily write a safe version of `Show` and `Read` that checks the correctness of the `length`. Also this isn't really like an SQL injection; this simply creates malformed data but doesn't execute anything.

Comment: @Bakuriu I agree, that's what I mean by "obvious way" in the first sentence. To just not be naive with it. That aside, you may find or may not find resemblance to SQL injection but either way this can lead to security problems. Even if you only consider execution: execution that depends on data is a subset of when this problem would occur, and I'd argue that it's very frequent as-well.